# For any field $K$, $t^3+xt+1$ is either irreducible or splits in $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

There is weaker question [Show that over any field $K$, such that $\mathbb Q \subset K$ the polynomial $x^3-3x+1$ is either irreducible or splits into linear factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251497/show-that-over-any-field-k-such-that-mathbb-q-subset-k-the-polynomial-x). I tried to use the same method as follows:

> Call $y_1,y_2,y_3$ the roots of $t^3−xt+1$ in $K$. You can compute $Δ=(y_1−y_2)^2(y_1−y_3)^2(y_2−y_3)^2$. It is symmetric when permuting the roots, so $Δ\in K$ (it is the discriminant of the polynomial).
>
> Then, compute $δ′=(y_1−y_2)(y_1−y_3)\in K(y_1)$. If $Δ=δ_2$ with $δ\in K$, then $(y_2−y_3)^2=(\delta/\delta ' )^2$, and thus $(y_2−y_3)=±δ/δ′∈K(y_1)$. Combining this with $y_2+y_3=−y_1∈K(y_1)$, you obtain the expressions of $y_2$ and $y_3$ in $K(y_1)$.

The thing is, $Δ=4x^3-27$ is not always a square of some elements in $K$, so this arguement is not always true.

Another solution is as follows:

> $f=t^3-xt+1=(t-a)(t^2+at+a^2-x)$. Assume $a\in K$, and another zero of $f$ ,$b$, contains in $K(a)$. Then $b=\alpha a^2+\beta a + \gamma$. Notes that $a^3=xa-1$, now solve equation $b^3 = xb-1$.

I think it may works, but the calculation is so complex.

Can you please give some suggestions?

Comment: You mix together $\;t,\,x\;$ , which is not a good idea, imo. The polynomial seems to be in $\;t\;$ , whereas $\;x\;$ seems to be a scalar. Is this correct? This is very confusing because in your explanation you talk of the polynomial $\;x^3-3x+1\;$ , where $\;x\;$ is now the usual unknown for polynomials...

Comment: Sorry! I was considering the weaker version and I made some mistakes.

Comment: Hmm. $t^3 - 2t + 1 = (t - 1)(t^2 + t - 1)$ is neither irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ nor does it split in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general claim is false.  For example, take $x=0$.  Then $t^3+1$ has a root in $\Bbb{Q}$ itself but does not split there.  That $-3$ is important.  First it makes the polynomial irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$.  Second, it makes the discriminant be $4\cdot3^3-27 = 81$, which is a rational square, which implies that the Galois group over $\Bbb{Q}$ is $A_3$ so that the splitting field has degree $3$.  That means adjoining a root, which gives a degree 3 extension within the splitting field, gives the entire splitting field and so splits the polynomial into linear factors.  And since the polynomial is a cubic, if there is no root it remains irreducible, so in any extension it is irreducible or split into linear factors.